# is there a faster version of fminbnd in matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am now using `fminbnd` in Matlab, and I find it relatively slow (I am using it inside a nested loop). The function itself, its interface and the values it returns are great, but when looking into the .m file I see it is not optimized. As a matter of fact, I was hoping for something like that to be written as a mex.

Anyone knows of an alternative to `fminbnd` that works much faster and does not have as much overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's written like that because it has to evaluate (`feval`) your user-defined function(s) on every iteration. Matlab's ODE solvers work in the same way. In current Matlab it's costly for a C/C++ code to call a user-defined Matlab function and read in its return values iteratively.

Make sure you're using the options correctly, that [`fminbnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) is the correct tool (maybe a simpler scheme would be better or, since this in a loop, maybe a multi-dimensional method like [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) would be more appropriate), and have optimized your objective function. The next easiest thing would be to try compiling your Matlab code to C or C++ (see [`codgen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html)). You'll likely need to compile in your objective function, and all of the options, as well in order to avoid the slowdown issues mentioned above. I've not tried this for `fminbnd`, but I did see mention of it working online. If your objective function itself is complicated, you could try just converting it to a mex function.

`fminbnd` is based on [Brent's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent's_method). You can find C, C++, and FORTRAN code for that [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/brent/brent.html). The [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) also has a version: [`gsl_min_fminimizer_brent`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Minimization-Algorithms.html).

Comment: Do you happen to know whether the matlab routine uses the local or global minimiser and, if the latter, what it uses as second derivative bound?

Comment: @RDGuida: `fminbnd` returns a value that is the local minimizer (this is also detailed in the documentation). If you need a global optimization scheme, then you may want to try one of [methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/functionlist.html) available in the [Global Optimization toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/index.html).