# Margin of optimisation in C++ armadillo code

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, optimization, armadillo

I am trying to migrate a quite complex matlab funciton in c++ using the library `armadillo` but I have serious problems in terms of performance (my c++ version is much slower than the matlab one which is a bit odd). I was wondering whether any of you can spot a point where I can improve my code and possibly can give me some suggestions. The problem is created by a bit in which I try to minimise a function. This is the matlab code

```
lambda = fminbnd(@SSE, lower_limit,upper_limit,options, y0, x); 

function L=SSE(lambda, alpha, y) 
N=size(y,2);
len=size(y,1);
for i=1:N
    z(:,i)=jglog(y(:,i),alpha,lambda);
end
s = 0;    
mean_spec=mean(z,2);
for i=1:N        
    for j=1:len            
        s = s + (z(j,i)-mean_spec(j,1))^2;
    end
end    
L=s;

end

function z=glog(y,alpha,lambda) % Glog transform  
z=log((y-alpha)+sqrt((y-alpha).^2+lambda));
end

function [zj, gmn]=jglog(y,y0,lambda)    
z=glog(y,y0,lambda);
gmn=exp(mean(log(sqrt((y-y0).^2+lambda))));
zj=z.*gmn;
end
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751636/is-there-a-faster-version-of-fminbnd-in-matlab) I downloaded the c++ version of the matlab minimisation code (brent's method). You can find it [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/brent/brent.cpp).

This is my c++ version.

```
class SSE_c : public brent::func_base   //create functor
{
    public:
        mat A;
        double offset;
        virtual double operator() (double lam)
        {
            return SSE(A,offset,lam);
        }
        SSE_c(mat a,double of) {A=a;offset=of;}
};

SSE_c fun(x,y0);

brent::glomin(low_limit,up_limit,c,100,step_threshold,step_threshold,fun,lambda);

double SSE(mat& m,double ofs,double lam)
{
    mat z(m.n_rows,m.n_cols);

    for(uint i=0;i<m.n_cols;i++)
        z.col(i) = jglog(m.col(i),ofs,lam);

    std::cout << "Iteration:" << count++;

    double s=0;
    vec mean_spec(z.n_rows);
    FuncOnMatRows(z,mean_spec,[](rowvec const& w){return mean(w);});
    for(uint i=0;i<z.n_cols;i++)
        for(uint j=0;j<z.n_rows;j++)
            if(is_finite(z(j,i)))
                s += pow((z(j,i)-mean_spec(j)),2);
    return s;
}

vec jglog(vec&& v,double ofs,double lam)
{
    vec g=glogF(v,ofs,lam);
    double gmn;
    vec interm = log(sqrt(square(v-ofs)+lam));
    if(interm.is_finite())
        gmn=exp(mean(interm));
    else
        gmn=exp(mean(interm.elem(find_finite(interm))));    
    g = g*gmn;    
    return g;
}

vec glogF(vec&& v,double ofs,double lam)
{
    return glogF(v,ofs,lam);
}

vec glogF(vec& v,double ofs,double lam)
{
    vec z = log((v-ofs)+sqrt(square(v-ofs)+lam));
    return z;
}

template<typename Func>
void FuncOnMatRows(const mat& M,vec& v,Func const & func)
{
    for(uint i=0;i<M.n_rows;i++)     // operation calculated on rows
    {
        if(M.row(i).is_finite())
            v(i) = func(M.row(i));
        else if(!any(M.row(i)>0))
            v(i) = NAN;
        else
        {
            rowvec b=M.row(i);
            v(i) = func(b.elem(find_finite(b)).t());    //output of .elem is always colvec, so transpose
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without having looked at the MATLAB code too closely, but it seems like the loops could be vectorised?

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean: I could remove one of the `for` loop at the end of `SSE`. Do you you spot anything else?